# Bash Shell URL built with variables are missing after inserting behind http://

Tags: bash, variable

I have a bash shell script that performs a curl command that is made of variables:

```
# Variables
URL="http://$UN:$PW@localhost:8080/rest/v1"
```

The $UN and $PW are populated by a read command further within the script when a user logins in...

```
# Login
echo "Please enter your username and password."
read -p "Username: " UN
read -s -p "Password: " PW
```

lets assume at login the username is set to "alice" and the password set to something secure like "password".

The problem I have is that the $UN and $PW variables appear empty when the $URL is built i.e. the URL should look like this: 
http://alice:password@localhost:8080/rest/v1 but instead I'm seeing http://:@localhost:8080/rest/v1

if I echo the variables in the script I can see the UN and PW variables have been populated:

```
echo $UN
```

returns alice

```
echo $PW
```

returns password but if I

```
echo $URL
```

they're missing

I suspect this is something to do with the final / in the http:// but I could be wrong.  Note I've tried changing inserting the variables into the $URL variable in different ways...

```
"http://${UN}:${PW}@localhost:8080/rest/v1"

"http://"$UN":"$PW"@localhost:8080/rest/v1"

"http://"${UN}":"${PW}"@localhost:8080/rest/v1"
```

...but the results are the same.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the $URL variable **after** the $UN and $PW, like this:

```
echo "Please enter your username and password."
read -p "Username: " UN
read -s -p "Password: " PW
URL="http://${UN}:${PW}@localhost:8080/rest/v1"
```